# Codeigniter, get value from exploded string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I Have 3 tables in my DB :

```
t_keg:ID|keg_name|time_start|time_end|place
t_keg_detail:ID|keg_ID|int_audience|ext_audience
t_user:ID|name|
```

the value of int_audience is string which is ID from t_user. Ex:1001,1002,1003.

So far i have generated view for specific t_keg joined t_detail based on t_keg's ID.

```
ID|keg_name|time_start|time_end|int_audience|ext_audience
1|Workshop|2015-08-16|2015-08-20|1001,1002,1003|Phil, Harry, Duke
```

But, i want to get the name's value from t_user based on int_audience's value.
So, it would look like:

```
1|Workshop|2015-08-16|2015-08-20|Linus, Snape, Dumbledore|Phil, Harry, Duke
```

Please help!

Edit:
Sorry, forgot to write the explode part.

I tried to explode the int_audience

```
$aud=$data[0]->int_audience;
$aud_res=explode(',',$aud);
```

where $data is an array from select t_keg join t_keg_detail

then I use foreach to select from t_user where id=$aud_res

```
        foreach ($aud_res as $x) {
            $this->db->select('name');
            $this->db->from('t_users');
            $this->db->where('ID',$x);
            $query = $this->db->get()->result();
            $data['peserta']=$query;
        }
            print_r($data);
```

but i get only one name from int_audience (the last one).

How can i get all audience's name?

And put them in $data?

Comment: Please include the Sql/MySql used

Comment: Tried using GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: Also, how and why are we dealing with an "exploded string"? Plus, would be helpful to see the data types of the tables used - perhaps you could include the table schemas?

Comment: In mysql you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get delimited values, however I think the approach to your table design needs re-thinking - the values for int_audience and ext_audience would be better stored one per row rather than several per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think yout problem is that you are allways overriding the value

```
foreach ($aud_res as $x) {
     $this->db->select('name');
     $this->db->from('t_users');
     $this->db->where('ID',$x);
     $query = $this->db->get()->result();
     $data['peserta']=$query; //so you are putting the value in the same place
```

}
   print_r($data);

so try this instead

```
foreach ($aud_res as $x) {
         $this->db->select('name');
         $this->db->from('t_users');
         $this->db->where('ID',$x);
         $query = $this->db->get()->result();
         $data['peserta'][]=$query;
   }
print_r($data);
```

this way tou will be adding values and not telling the array value to be the last row.

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. Just like what i wanted.